# How to make a function that makes a large array from sub arrays both efficient and readable?

Tags: python, numpy

I've got a function that essentially generates several smaller numpy arrays and concatenates them together into one big one. It roughly looks like this:

```
def make_big_array(second, third):
   big_array = make_first()
   if second:
      big_array +=  make_second()
   if third:
      big_array += make_third()
   return big_array
```

Basically, I have a coordinator function that checks whether the `big array` should include some sub arrays, makes them, then adds them to the `big_array` it wants to return. However, I presume it's inefficient to first make each array then concatenate it to the end of the `big_array`.

I guess an alternative might be to use `second` and `third` to workout how long the `big_array` will eventually be and then pass `make_second()` and `make_third()` `big_array` and an index for where to start filling it in, but this doesn't seem very readable. Anyone got any suggestions on how to make this fast and readable?

Comment: Are you using `+=` in the list join sense?  Because in `numpy` that's numeric addition.

Comment: One way or other you are going to make 2 arrays (unless there's some magic inside `make_second()`).  It doesn't matter much whether you then copy those arrays to the appropriate slice of a preallocated `big_array`, or collect them in a list, and do one `concatenate`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create all arrays separately and then concatenate them in one go:

```
def make_big_array(second, third):
    arrays = [make_first()]
    if second:
        arrays.append(make_second())
    if third:
        arrays.append(make_third())
    return np.concatenate(arrays)
```

Comment: That definitely looks readable, but how efficient is it? Presumably more so than my method but isn't it quite a bit slower than just getting each function to append its values rather than create a sub-array?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in this [article](http://chrisschell.de/2018/02/01/how-to-efficiently-deal-with-huge-Numpy-arrays.html) its advised to preallocate an array and store the values in it. Using this method, the program does not need to change the size of array each time an array is appended to the original array. You can do this for your case:

```
a = np.random.rand(1000000, 10)
second = np.random.rand(5000, 10)
third = np.random.rand(4000, 10)
if second:
    new = np.empty([len(a)+len(second), a.shape[1]])
    new[:len(a)] = a
    new[len(a):] = second
if third:
    new = np.empty([len(a)+len(third), a.shape[1]])
    new[:len(a)] = a
    new[len(a):] = third
```

But as long as you are just concatenating two arrays, the efficiency gained by this way is negligible.

Comment: The idea is good. It can be improved by using `np.empty` which is the most efficient way to preallocate memory

Comment: While the general idea in the linked article is fine, it is poorly coded.  In particular this line `np.append(results, [processed_entry])` is deeply flawed.  `np.append` does not operate in-place.